# Facebook linter does not see some of my cms pages

Tags: facebook-opengraph

My site is wordpress based for the main part and has another part based on Zenphoto (with a theme including the wordpress theme layout)
I had noticed the missing like buttons for some of the zenphoto pages (not all) but thoughts "I'll take care of that later ..."

I worked later on some php to get the open graph tags (image, url) and noticed that they were not recieved by FB for some pages (the same I mentioned earlier, as I noticed later.)

### Passing them to the linter I saw that it does not see them.

Example :

http://www.voirleloup.com/galerie/catalogue/

(like buttons are not displayed)
This is a zenphoto page that gets in the linter :
"Response Code :    404"
and
"See exactly what our scraper sees for your URL"
... Gives me a blank page.

---

Second example
http://www.voirleloup.com/galerie/

... another zenphoto page that the linter sees perfectly (like buttons work)

As the linter gives us no clue, I don't know what causes this problem in the first page, and that does not in the second ...
Any help will be most welcome,
Thanks,
Nicolas

Answer (score 0):

> This is a zenphoto page that gets in the linter : "Response Code : 404"

Well, it gives that same response code in a browser, too – which you could have easily verified yourself, using Firebug for example.

Yes, an HTML document containing what is obviously meant to be page content and not just an error message is returned as well – but a tool like the linter can not decide if it’s an error message or actual content, that would require much more AI than such a tool is required to have. It relies on the HTTP response code your server sends it.

> Second example […] another zenphoto page that the linter sees perfectly

That has a response code of 200 OK.

So this is not a problem with the linter, but with your page. What exactly goes wrong, can not be told from the outside. So start checking your server’s log files, and your CMS configuration.

Comment: Thanks CBroe, To be honest, I had never heard of the HTTP response code before using the linter, so I thought it was a linter thing. All this sounds like witchery to me : How can we get the page and its content but get that 404 code in the same time ? Now I'am on my way for digging into the logs ...  Thanks for your answer